# How to make sub folder exculsive access via sub domain only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, shared-hosting

I have web site hosted on shared hosting account which is managed by CPanel. It allows to create unlimited sub-domains. I have the following situation:

Suppose that my primary domain there is: mydomain.com
My account's files are found on the hosting server at /home/myaccount/public_html
I decided to make sub-domain named dir i.e dir.mydomain.com
I created this sub-domain to use the following file:
/home/myaccount/public_html/Hosts/directory

Now I, successfully, able to access http://dir.mydomain.com
However, I need to prevent the access http://mydomain.com/Hosts/directory and exclusively restrict the access to the sub-domain.

How could I achieve this using .htaccess?

The following is a copy of the code I use in the .htaccess file found in /home/myaccount/public_html/Hosts/directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
AddType audio/mpeg mp3
AddType text/xml xml
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above answer of Jon Lin does not work. I found that Redirect may solve the problem as follows:

```
#.htaccess at public_html

Redirect /Hosts/directory/ http://dir.mydomain.com/
```

Answer (score 2):

Leave the rules that are in `/home/myaccount/public_html/Hosts/directory` where they are, you need to add rules to your main document root, `/home/myaccount/public_html` of your primary domain so that it can't access stuff in Hosts:

```
RewriteRule ^/?Hosts - [L,R=404]
```

You'll need to add this before any rules you may already have that does routing. From your main domain, any accesses to `/Hosts` or any subdirectory will result in a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution. Short and Simple.

http://www.codefleet.net/prevent-access-to-subdomain-folder-from-main-domain/